# RxJava2: Change events with PublishSubject on a given scheduler?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

**Challenge:** I want to have one **Repository** that produces queries (`Query<T>`) which the caller can specify schedulers for, and manipulate in whichever way it wants, **that in turn also** auto-updates as change events are internally propagated through a bus (PublishSubject, *unless theres a better way? Let me know*).

It is important that the schedulers come from the caller, and are not "inherited" straight from the repository; as some queries will be combined and as such cannot come from different threads. Basically, I want to be able to specify the scheduler for the whole observable chain with the possibility to have multiple query observables in there.

**Generally speaking - this works fine... *But*** as soon as change events are introduced into the picture, things get real messy, real quick. From my understanding this is because the subject will propagate its events on the same thread as the caller. This results in the `Query<T>` above doing its work on different schedulers depending on where the `subject.onNext(..)` is called, and herein lies the challenge.

**How can I force ChangeEvents through a PublishSubject to be observed on the same scheduler as the `Observable<Query<T>>` that it creates? Without explicitly specifying .observeOn()?**

I am open to different approaches to my challenge, but from my experimentation this seems to be the "right" way to do it. Please enlighten me if theres another way to go about it.

```
interface Query<T>{
    T findFirst();
}

Repository repo = new Repository();

repo.createQuery(IceCream.class) //Returns Observable<Query<IceCream>>
    .map(it.findFirst())         //Returns IceCream
    .map(it -> it.getName())     //Returns "Magnum Choco"
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(it -> Timber.d("Got IceCream with name: %s",it))
```

I appreciate your wisdom and help. Sorry for the icecream cravings.

Comment: Nicely explained your challenge, My knowledge can you try [this](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite) one help to your 1.specify schedulers user way 2. auto-updates control user options 3. multiple query observables

Comment: Thank you @RajeshRajendiran, Ive already checked out their library (which is great) but it doesnt suit my needs unfortunately.

Comment: Are you free to change the repository API? Because AFAIK the only way to do this is to add a the caller-supplied `observeOn` between the subscriber and the query.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos I have full control + its early enough for me to make big changes. I was afraid Id need to add an observeOn (which in turn enforces me to specify the full spec of schedulers, as the query is limited to its current thread [realm]).